# Database of self-inflicted injuries?

Tags: data-request, medical

I need a database of self-inflicted injuries, their prevalence, age, gender and area distribution and the nature of the injury. This is very specific but could have a huge impact in my research. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: WISQARS? http://www.cdc.gov/injury/wisqars/

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like very interesting research.

There is a database of self-inflicted injuries and suicide from the U.S. Centers for Disease Control and Prevention.  [Faststats](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/suicide.htm) has both summary and detailed information about this.  There is a related set of data on [unintentional injuries](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/fastats/accidental-injury.htm) that may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[National Electronic Injury Surveillance System (NEISS)](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Research--Statistics/NEISS-Injury-Data/)**

> Date (one year maximum range; e.g., how many injuries were treated in 1996)
>
> Product (e.g., how many bicycle injuries occurred)
>
> Sex (e.g., how many injuries occurred to women)
>
> Age (e.g., how many injuries occurred to people aged 35-55)
>
> Diagnosis (e.g., how many lacerations occurred)
>
> Disposition (e.g., how many people were admitted to the hospital)
>
> Locale (e.g., how many injuries occurred at a school)
>
> Body part (e.g., how many injuries involved the knee)

Here is the link to the [Query Tool](http://www.cpsc.gov/cgibin/NEISSQuery/home.aspx)

(source: [QZ](http://qz.com/609255/the-injuries-most-likely-to-land-you-in-an-emergency-room-in-america/), and their [twitter-bot](https://twitter.com/usinjuries))